# What is the cardinality of the following equivalence classes?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have the relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $a\sim b \iff [\exists q\in \mathbb{Q}: a-b=q\pi]$. What are the possible cardinalities of the equivalence classes?

Comment: This seems related to the [Hamel basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Related_notions) of $\mathbb{R}$ when viewed as a [vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are looking at $\mathbf{R} / \pi \mathbf{Q}$. A class has the same cardinal as $\mathbf{Q}$ (all classes are in bijection with $\pi\mathbf{Q}$, thus with $\mathbf{Q}$, and the set of classe has the same cardinal as $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: But if all the classes are in bijection with $\mathbb{Q}$, how can the set of classes have the same cardinal as $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Greentree1912: Because the _number_ of such classes is uncountable.

Comment: For the same reason that all $\{x\}$ for real $x$ are finite and countable but $\mathbf{R}$ is infinite and not countable. Because the number of classes has not the cardinality of $\mathbf{N}$.

More precisely, as $\pi \not=0$, you can complete the family $(\pi)$ in a basis $(x_i)_i$ of $\mathbf{R}$ over $\mathbf{Q}$,  where let's say $i_0$ is the only $i_0$ such that $x_{i_0} = \pi$. Then $\mathbf{R} / \pi \mathbf{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_{i\not= i_0} x_i \mathbf{Q}$, and this one has the same cardinal as $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: To finish, all of this requires the "fact" that there is no cardinal strictly inbetween cardinals of $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: @Robert: That is the Continuum Hypothesis! You certainly don't need CH to prove that $\mathbb R/\pi\mathbb Q$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I am really looking forward to see you showing this without the axiom of choice. Already to construct $\mathbf{R}$... But even without this.

Comment: I said you didn't need CH. I said nothing about AC. (But you certainly don't need AC to construct $\mathbb R$.) BTW, if you reply, please put @TonyK somewhere in your comment, so that I get notified.